# Complex sorting lines in SAP B1

Tags: sapb1

This is a question already posted on [another forum](https://answers.sap.com/questions/384221/complex-sorting-of-lines.html) but it has not yet recieved any answers:

We have a requirement to enter all our purchase orders to a particular client in a special way so they can eneter it directly into their system from our order. Doing it manually takes us a lot of time having to simply add rows as the order is created. If I could somehow overcome this either via a button or a user process it would be great. See below the way we need to sort:

1. By Length - this needs to be numerical sort i.e. 12 needs to be after 9 not between 1 and 2
2. Then by Colour - retaining the length sort for each colour we then need to sort by colour - doesn't need to be alphabetical, just grouped in colour type
3. Then by item code - there is only 2 item codes concerned. Same as above, retaning the previous 2 sortings we need to then sort by these item codes.

So at the top you wil have all the "Item Code A" items in Pink from shortest to longest. Then you will have all the "Item Code A" items in Green from shortest to longest. Then you will have all "Item code B" items in Pink from shortest to longest. Finally you will have all the "Item Code B" items in Green from shortest to longest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query 
just change the values to fit your DB

```
SELECT T1.[ItemCode], T1.[Quantity], T2.[SLength1], T2.[SHeight1], T2.[Width] 
FROM OPOR T0
INNER JOIN POR1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.[ItemCode] = T2.[ItemCode] 
WHERE T0.[CardCode] = [%0]
ORDER BY T2.[ItemCode], T2.[SHeight1], T2.[SWidth1], T2.[SLength1]
```